# Create a Plugin-Based System Like Wordpress With Laravel / PHP

Tags: laravel, plugins, modular-design

This question has been bugging me for quite some time now, I want to create a cms, a School Mnagement System to be more specific, and what matters to me the most, is making this system plugin based, in a way that administrators can download and install plugins right through their admin panel, just like wordpress.

Now I've read about wordpress **Hooks**, **Actions** and **Filters**, and in all honesty i can say i'm just a little familiar with their functionality, but to apply same functionality to a **Laravel App**... , It's a bit hard to figure out, at least for me.

I've also searched about this question and found out that almost everyone is suggesting packages, But while packages can work great for other developers wanting to get use of the package's functionality, they can't be easily installed by a user not familiar with any programming language, And that's exactly what i want in my application.

Now what i have in my mind so far, as in **Wordpress Actions** and **Filters**, almost everything one would want to use in Wordpress theme files ( to make that piece of code flexible for adding plugin functionality ) should be called as functions, and calling that function by Wordpress do_action() is kind of a must-take path, which of course makes sense.

This way plugin developers can just call add_action() / add_filter() in their files and put their plugins into the flow of the application.
So...

Basically what I'm asking here is:

> - **How to apply such functionality to a laravel app?**
> - **Is there an easier way than calling everything by a function like do_action()?**
> - **Should i write some kind of a file management module for downloading and updating plugins?**

Again I must say that I am not very familiar with wordpress ways to achieve this kind of functionality, So I may be wrong about some of the description I mentioned above, But please, I appreciate any clarification around this subject if you can.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

*P.S. I've tried to be as clear as I possibly can about the problem, And I'm not looking for any specific method for the system I`m developing.
What i want is to know Common / Best methods ( If there is a best method ) for achieving such functionality, preferably in Laravel, but a general algorithm would still be very appreciated.

I know lots of people have the same question and are tackling with the same issue, so if you even only provide a link to a useful article it would be great.*

Comment: hello did you got your solution? I also have the same requirement now.

Answer (score 10):

I have been working as a Wordpress Developer for a very long time and I also have sufficient experience in Laravel... and to be honest, making this kind of functionality is not that difficult at all.

### How?

First of all, you must understand that the web app that you will be making will have all the functionalities, but they can only be enabled/disabled from the front-end (Admin Panel/Dashboard). In other words, your School Management System app is actually having all the features/functionalities pre-installed, but you are just allowing the users to enable/disable it. This is much simpler.

So, if for eg. you want to provide someone `attendance management` functionality, you will have to give the admin of the site, the access to enable/disable it.

### Why?

Wordpress has a built-in UI for adding/updating plugins. But in Laravel, everything is code based and therefore this I believe is the simplest way to go (especially for making things in your app pluggable).

### Steps

1. Make a site with UI etc...
2. Create a config and migration file which will have the names of all the plugins you are going to allow the user to enable/disable.
3. Make a sync command that will sync all the plugins in your app.
4. Use it render a page from the front-end and manage their status from the back-end (is_active etc etc...)
5. Now once, these plugins are active, make sure the user (say moderator, editor) has access to manage them, for which you will obviously have to create roles/permissions and use **Laravel Policies** for such stuff.
6. Lastly, only the admin will have the enabling/disabling writes and no one else.

For the other part where you want the people to perform their own functions with **filters**/**actions**. I'd say this is completely contradictory to the part where you say `Installing Laravel Packages isn't easy`. Well, if you would really want a developer a way into this, why not straight away ask them to make a package for your app alone? Hmmmm.... Think about it :)

But, even then, if you would like to create such a functionality, create a simple class which the user can call and user its functions to call their own functions... Something like -> `SMSPlugin::do_action()`. But then again, making things like updating/deleting the plugin will require you to build your own **Plugin Store** and ask users to upload to it. Then you'll have to make an API to constantly check for updates for all the installed plugins and blah blah.... It's a really long procedure... And I don't believe that feasible too!

Hope I answered everything. Let me know in the comments if you have any doubts :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, But the most important thing in this precedure ( At least for me ) is that an administrator should be able to install new plugins that will be developed at later dates. Lets just leave the part about other developers for a while, lets say I maintain the plugin store myself, the main challenge for me is to be able to add new functionality to the systems from their admin panels. Otherwise I'd have to manually install each plugin on each system when they are released, and that's certainly not what a developer wants.

Comment: And when i said  "Installing Laravel Packages isn't easy" I was talking about users ( Maybe School Administrator in case of my project ), not other developers.

Comment: Yeah, so in that case... You can simply go ahead by making a store and then maintaining an API to check for regular updates. But like I said, if you are going to maintain the store yourself... its better to add them to the main package and allow the admin to enable/disable them. Secondly, since someone will have to run the server/site from the back-end... a command such as `composer update arsi/sms` will have to be run to update the site. For running such commands, shell & root access are necessary (especially on live server).... So, one command is only what is required for upgrade. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But as i mentioned before, Its not just about automatically updating, what i want is to add NEWLY DEVELOPED PLUGINS to add more functionality. So i cant build all of them at first and let the user enable and disable them.This way is very simple, and there`s no question in it. What i am asking is a way to add NEW plugins to my system from the admin panel. This is what i want, system being able to automatically download and install them. I cant have a plugin store that just updates already install plugins.I want to add new functionality,just like Wordpress.

Comment: @Arsi I know what you are asking for here... And i specified it in my answer that please prefer to make all the features (including new plugins) a part of the package and ask the user to upgrade only the `sms` package. Once the main package is updated, the user will see new plugins as well. I know what functionality you are looking for here... but Laravel doesn't offer such upgrades. Obviously, when something like `composer dump-autoload` is required to run it, I am sure, addition of new php files will also require that and it is not secure to run such a command without sudo/root privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I know it was 2 years ago, but for now you can achieve this with laravel with some packages:

So i think the steps will be:

- Create new Laravel App and add some packages for BASIC admin UI and things you will need like:
- Authentication (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)
- Roles and Permissions (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)
- Users managment
- Modules (https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v4/introduction)

At this point you must configure and write a UI for manage every thing from every package mentioned.

So i think this is the way or at least some try to do it in 2019 :D

Happy new year to all!

Comment: I am thinking to create a separate repo from front end . Is it possible or wise  to build plugins system in microservice?

Comment: Yes, you can make an API with all these, then write the frontend with your preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package for this, it supports version 5, didn't test yet with 6:
https://github.com/oneso/laravel-plugins